# How do I get the classname of the active window?

Tags: c#

By using this code I can get the title of the active window..

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder text, int count);

private string GetActiveWindowTitle()
{
    const int nChars = 256;
    IntPtr handle = IntPtr.Zero;
    StringBuilder Buff = new StringBuilder(nChars);
    handle = GetForegroundWindow();

    if (GetWindowText(handle, Buff, nChars) > 0)
    {
        return Buff.ToString();
    }
    return null;
```

But how should I do to get the classname of the active window?

Comment: User32's [GetClassNameA](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getclassname) call? -- *See Also [This support.microsoft Doc](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/112649)*

Comment: Do you mean the window class, in Win32 terms, or do you mean the name of the C# class behind the window?

Answer (score 5):

Simply pinvoke GetClassName().  This returns the *Windows* class name for a window, it doesn't have anything to do with a C# class.  Getting the C# class name for a window in another process is not possible.  Take a look at the [Managed Spy++ tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163617.aspx) for possible hacks if this is a Winforms app.

Answer (score 2):

I expanded Hans Passant's answer into working code:

Usage:

```
string className = Spy.GetForegroundWindowClassName();
```

Class:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

public static class Spy
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private static extern int GetClassName(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpClassName, int nMaxCount);

    public static string GetForegroundWindowClassName()
    {
        IntPtr hWnd = GetForegroundWindow();
        var className = new StringBuilder(256);
        GetClassName(hWnd, className, className.Capacity);
        return className.ToString();
    }
}
```

Side Note: in my case, I just needed a basic utility to tell me the class name of a window so I could reference that in my C# code.  After writing the code above, I realized I could achieve the same thing using pre-existing utilities.  One such utility I see mentioned often in the C# community is Visual Studio's Spy++ tool.  I didn't bother trying that since it requires downloading 2.5 GB of C++ components.  Instead, I used the "Window Spy" tool that comes with Autohotkey.  [Autohotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) is a tiny download compared to what's needed for Spy++, so I think it's a good option if it suits your needs.

[image: autohotkey window spy screenshot]