# logon dialog handler windows 7

Tags: c#, watin

```
using System.Windows.Automation;
using System.Linq;
using WatiN.Core.DialogHandlers;
using WatiN.Core.Native.Windows;

namespace DialogHandlers
{
public class Windows7LogonDialogHandler : LogonDialogHandler
{
    #region Private Fields

    private readonly string _mUsername;
    private readonly string _mPassword;
    private readonly AndCondition _mListCondition = new AndCondition(new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.IsEnabledProperty, true), new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.ListItem));
    private readonly AndCondition _mEditCondition = new AndCondition(new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.IsEnabledProperty, true), new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Edit));
    private readonly AndCondition _mButtonConditions = new AndCondition(new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.IsEnabledProperty, true), new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Button));

    #endregion

    #region Constructor

    public Windows7LogonDialogHandler(string username, string password)
        : base(username, password)
    {
        _mUsername = username;
        _mPassword = password;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Public Members

    public override bool HandleDialog(Window window)
    {
        if (CanHandleDialog(window))
        {
            var win = AutomationElement.FromHandle(window.Hwnd);
            var lists = win.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, _mListCondition);
            var buttons = win.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, _mButtonConditions);
            var another = (from AutomationElement list in lists
                           where list.Current.ClassName == "UserTile"
                           where list.Current.Name == "Use another account"
                           select list).First();
            another.SetFocus();

            foreach (var edit in from AutomationElement list in lists
                                 where list.Current.ClassName == "UserTile"
                                 select list.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, _mEditCondition)
                                     into edits
                                     from AutomationElement edit in edits
                                     select edit)
            {
                if (edit.Current.Name.Contains("User name"))
                {
                    edit.SetFocus();
                    var usernamePattern = edit.GetCurrentPattern(ValuePattern.Pattern) as ValuePattern;
                    if (usernamePattern != null) usernamePattern.SetValue(_mUsername);
                }
                if (edit.Current.Name.Contains("Password"))
                {
                    edit.SetFocus();
                    var passwordPattern = edit.GetCurrentPattern(ValuePattern.Pattern) as ValuePattern;
                    if (passwordPattern != null) passwordPattern.SetValue(_mPassword);
                }
            }
            foreach (var submitPattern in from AutomationElement button in buttons
                                          where button.Current.AutomationId == "SubmitButton"
                                          select button.GetCurrentPattern(InvokePattern.Pattern) as InvokePattern)
            {
                submitPattern.Invoke();
                break;
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public override bool CanHandleDialog(Window window)
    {
        return window.ClassName == "#32770";
    }

    #endregion
}
```

}

At line: public override bool HandleDialog(Window window) 
It needs a value for window and as i am testing a website, i dont have the name or code for that window.
Please suggest an alternative for this

Comment: Check [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5476190/how-do-i-get-the-classname-of-the-active-window] out... Might help you...  
Thanks, Sham_

Comment: No..I dont have sourcecode for this window and its not working that way..is there any other method to handle logon dialog handler in windows 7

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you looking to? Is it a window (dialog) which has two text fields and a button to submit the credentials? Is that dialog launches from your web app?

Comment: Yes. When I open a website,it first gives a logon prompt with two textfields to enter username and password and two buttons of ok and cancel and there is no source code for login prompt,so I have to handle that prompt using watin in my c# code.

Comment: For windows using WatiN, there is no complete solution. You need to use different tool for it. or as a temporary solution. Try to send keys (assuming the focus will be in dialog).. `System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait(userName); System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("{TAB}");System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait(password);System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("{TAB}");  System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");.

Comment: I am using a web application that has logon dialog.

Comment: Can you suggest any alternate testing tool that is platform independent like Watin and i can handle logon dialge in that

Comment: Even though if you are using Web application the above code should work for you... There are many tools for Windows (GUI) automation. Like CodedUI, AutoIt...etc. Since you are familiar with C#, I would suggest Coded UI[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286681(v=vs.100).aspx]. After generating the code, you can even add it to your existing scripts as well. Or AutoIt, which is a scripting based framework which uses VB script.

Comment: Focus is not on the dialog so i can not use the temporary solution that you gave. Are you trying to say that the above code that I have mentioned will work??